# draw image like xperia gallery background

Tags: android, drawing, android-custom-view, image-gallery, ondraw

Xperia gallery draw random image from selected album with specific blur and scale effects.

i need to draw an image in my custom view like Xperia gallery background image.

like this sample image at background of album
[image: sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use BlurMaskFilter, you can set it via Paint.setMaskFilter()